# mysqldump not restoring data in MySql 5.0.19

Tags: mysql

I have a production and a development server, each server has its own MySql server. I am not the admin of any server, not installed anything. I need to get the schema and data from the production to the development but myslqdump does not restore any data!

I tried to add SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; without result. Then I removed the only trigger present, nothing. Then I removed two foreign keys that created and error (when importing phpMyAdmin). Then I was able to import the data.

This is quite scaring. I cannot rely on mysqldump, isn't? Did you have similar problems? Any advise?

Comment: The error was a foreign key, set to not null with default to 11. I changed it to null. Instead of using mysqldump I used mysql so I get the eoor that was cousing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

are you dumping and restoring with phpmyadmin? what error do you get?

for large mysql databases i recommend to user mysqldumper for dumping and restoring if you have no ssh access.

http://www.mysqldumper.net/

Comment: As stated in the title and body I am using mysqldump. Thanks for the link is interesting, but any DBMS should have its own reliable backup tool.